# Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects aka SMO nuget does not contain Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll

Tags: sql-server-2014, collation, gac, smo, sql-parser

I'm using CollationInfo Class for SQL Collation (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) specific string comparisons (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.metadata.collationinfo.aspx).

Once I installed SMO nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects#) I could add reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Metadata and use the CollationInfo class from visual studio. Everything runs fine on my dev machine.

But when I deployed the code to deployment server, exception was raised about not finding Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll. Because this dll is in my GAC on dev machine.

It's not part of SMO - Couldn't find it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies, neither was it part of build after installing the nuget. I could uninstall the nuget and everything still works fine on dev machine.

Question is - Is there any way to get this dll (and its dependencies if any) without installing anything on the deployment server? Is this file not available through any other nuget? Only other options is to package it up myself but that doesn't seem ideal.

Thanks!